# Node-REDでノードに設定した情報を削除したい

Tags: bluemix

Node-REDでwebsocketのリスナーやTwitterのアカウント情報などを削除したいです

新たに別のwebsocketやTwitterノードを作ると前に設定した情報が残っています
古いノード自体は何日も前に削除してもう存在しないのですが設定情報は消えないようです
ノードだけでなく設定情報も削除する方法はないでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configタブで設定した情報を削除することができます。

Node-REDの右上端をクリックしてドロップダウンメニューを表示し、「Sidebar」→「Configuration nodes」と選択してconfgタブを表示します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Node-REDに設定されているtwitter-credentialやwebsocket-listner等の情報がconfigタブに表示されるので、不要なものをダブルクリックしてDELETEで削除できます。